# Techniques for creating custom wix installers for multiple clients

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I'm creating an installer for a client at the moment but I know that I'll have to create another in a couple of weeks for a different client.  What techniques do people use to keep things tidy?  The only differences will be whether to include certain dlls with the installer and which initial config file to include.

I was thinking of creating a main wxs file which has most of the share installation information on it and a secondary file which would be customised to the client which would control which components should be included.

Either that or rewrite the main wxs file for each client but that means maintaining a full wxs file for each client with lots of duplicated information.

I assume many other people have come across this situation and I would like to know if I'm on the right path or if there are other much better solutions.

Thanks for any help, Neil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you choose will depend on how extensive the differences are going to be between the different client installers and how many different clients you'll have to support.

If you only have to maintain 2-3 client installers with max of 10 variables files between them just create a single shared .wxs file that brings in a client-specific .wxi based on build-time parameters.  It's easy enough to manually create and maintain 2-3 client-specific .wxi files.

If you have to maintain more clients, or there are 50 different possible dll/config file permutations I'd make use of WiX's [heat.exe](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm) "harvester" tool.  You would create a staging directory for every client you had to support that contained the dlls/config files required for each installer, use heat to harvest each directory into separate .wxs files, and then create a single shared .wxs file that would compile against each of the different harvested .wxs files to create the client installers.  This solution requires the build process to be a little more complicated, but it's easier than trying to maintain 20 different client-specific wix files.

Comment: Since we only have 2-3 clients at the moment I've gone for the easy option of having separate files for the time being.